# Fail to connect to mysql database using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I got an exception connecting to MySQL through Java. I downloaded the MySQL Java connector and added it to the `classpath`. I'm trying to connect to a MySQL table without success.

I have also tried to **telnet localhost 3306** but got the following error: **"nodename nor servname provided, or not known"**

The code is as follows:

```
//import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class ConnectToDatabase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{    
        //Accessing driver from the JAR file 
        Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance (); 

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cldatabase", "root", "root");

        //Here we create our query
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT * FROM profiles");

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        while(result.next()){ 
        System.out.println(result.getString("firstName") + " " +
            result.getString("lastName"));
    }
}
```

And this exception was thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.
    CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
```

I have xampp installed on my mac.

this is what comes up when I run "ps -ef | grep mysql"

0  1694     1   0   0:00.02 ??         0:00.03 /bin/sh /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql --pid-file=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/T-s-sMacBook-Air.local.pid
   -2  1792  1694   0   0:00.07 ??         0:00.28 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles --datadir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql --user=nobody --log-error=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/k-Air.local.err --pid-file=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/-MacBook-Air.local.pid --socket=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
  501  1814  1484   0   0:00.00 ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysql

Comment: Ummm... if telnet can't find your db how do you expect anything else to? It obviously isn't running or isn't running on that port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do any of the answers to this [similar question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/89955/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-through-jdbc-connector-through-tomcat-or-externally) help?

> 1) Verify the address mysql is bound
>   to, it's probably 127.0.0.1 (only)
>   which I believe is the default (at
>   least on standard Ubuntu server).
>   You'll have to comment out the
>   bind-address parameter in my.cnf to
>   bind to all available addresses (you
>   can't choose multiple, it's one or
>   all).
>
> 2) If it is bound to 127.0.0.1 and you
>   can't connect using "localhost", make
>   sure it's not resolving to the IPv6
>   localhost address instead of IPv4. (or
>   just use the IP address)
>
> 3) Double and triple-check the port
>   that mysql is listening on.
>
> 4) Make sure you're using the right
>   JDBC connector for your JDK.
>
> 5) Make sure you're not doing
>   something really silly like starting
>   mysql with --skip-networking.

What do you get when you run "`lsof -i :3306`" ?

Comment: How do I check which port mysql i listening to?

Comment: I have xampp installed on my mac

Comment: @Joal Halbert: the port is mentioned in my.cnf and it is the correct port 3306. I have tried all the options except comment the bind-address and point 5 which I don't understand

Comment: Strange I don't have a bind-address in my my.cnf ?

Comment: @Joel Halbert: When I try to telnet now it just say it refused?

Comment: What do you get when you run:  "lsof -i :3306" ??

Comment: @Joel Halbert: The output is nothing when I run it on the terminal?

Comment: If there's no output it means the mysql server is not listening on that port - and therein lies your problem. Check the mysql server logs, did it start - could it connect to the port? Is the firewall preventing it from listening on that port, is it even running?

Comment: @Joel Halbert: I can run my webapp on it, which is written in php instead of JAVA. So it must be running. are you sure it si the right command? because when I jsut run "lsof -i" I got a bunch of data

Comment: On Linux "lsof -i :3306" will tell you what is listening on port 3306, but check the man pages for your distro. Do you need to run it as root?

Comment: Ok I don't know if this mean anything but I can't run "mysql status" on the terminal command not found.

Comment: it might just mean your path is not set up correctly. Anyway, if you say you can connect to mysql and retrieve data from php then it must be running, right? What happens if you do "ps -ef | grep mysql" ?

Comment: I've already tried running it as root. what do you mean with distro?

Comment: OK, so it's running. Any useful information in the mysql log file? Try connecting using your program and see if anything is logged to the mysql log.

Comment: Where or how do I access the mysql log?

Comment: I tried this http://serverfault.com/questions/42531/where-is-my-mysql-log-on-os-x .And there is no error log for mysql. but htere is a log for xampp and it is not showing any signifant

Comment: Ok made a silly mistake I figured out that I haden't commented out the --skip-networking part. Which I didn't understood at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

if you are facing problem on Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); then copy mysql connector on following location..definately it will work..C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\lib\WEB-INF..note that in webapps folder there is no directory called lib then manually create lib and WEB-INF directory and paste mysql connector in that.no   need any classpath settings.....

if still you face problem then send your query...